# Какие иконки использовать: svg или font

Tags: svg, шрифты, icon

Я занимаюсь разработкой сайтов, дизайнов для них и скриптов довольно долго. И конечно же, непосредственно, создание дизайна почти не обходится без добавление разнообразных иконок, будь то иконка *play* или *menu*.

В 2012 году для таких целей использовали, почти везде и у меня в том числе, иконки картинками *png*, *gif*. Но, с нашими инновациями и усовершенствованием старых функций, теперь большинство сайтов перешли на рисование иконок *шрифтом (font)* или же на *svg*. Это позволяет сократить вес всех изображений и сделать их гибкими под разные размеры.

Но всё же, какие иконки лучше: svg или font? По моему мнению, лучше SVG, так как легче в использовании и имеет собственные плюшки.

**Какие иконки использовать: svg или font?**

Comment: `Жду ваших мнений по этому поводу.` ... - цитирую одну из причин закрытия вопросов "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ" :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а сейчас? Я основной вопрос жирным выделил :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Svg потому что:

1. Это векторный формат.
2. Иконка может быть многоцветной.
3. Svg можно инлайнить в html и стилизовать при помощи css.
4. Css позволяет добавить некую интерактивность в иконку.
5. Svg можно анимировать.
6. Нет проблем со скринридерами.
7. Не возникает проблем, если по какой-то причине браузер использует дефаултный шрифт.

Answer (score 2):

После долгого использования шрифтов-иконок, перешел на SVG и понял, что конкретно их различает по моему мнению:

1. Легкость в освоении и использовании - тут лучше шрифты с иконками, так как нет ничего проще, вставить готовые конкретные названия иконок в CSS элемента, либо ещё проще, установить библиотеку шрифтов и просто менять класс элемента.
2. Но теперь про функциональность и возможности - тут несомненно, как мне кажется, побеждает именно SVG, потому что с ним можно делать множество трансформаций и анимаций.
3. Размер - собственно эти 2 технологии популярны тем, что занимают очень маленький размер памяти, и оба хорошо справляются со своей задачей.
   Что в итоге, мне кажется, что лучше все же SVG, так как он имеет больше возможностей для дальнейшего его изменения, а потребляет примерно столько же ресурсов.

Answer (score -1):

Шрифт на то и сделан, чтобы хорошо отображать мелкие символы и значки. Браузер будет гораздо лучше отображать значки в формате шрифта, чем в SVG. Он подстроится под тип экрана, настройки сглаживания шрифтов.

Посмотрите мой пример. Я взял иконку из Font Awesome, выдернул ее из svg шрифта и вставил в inline svg. Специально для минусующих я сделал ее [Pixel-Perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZNre.png)

Покрутите размер шрифта, чтобы убедиться, что шрифт сохраняет четкость при масштабировании (что и не удивительно), a SVG хорош только на 14px и на достаточно больших размерах:

```js
$('input').on("change click",function(){
$('p').css('font-size',$('input').val()+'px')
})
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input value=16 type=number>

<p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> - Это шрифт</p>
<p><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14">

 <path d="M 7.25,6.5 Q 7.25,6.4 7.18,6.32 7.11,6.25 7,6.25 6.48,6.25 6.12,6.62 5.75,6.99 5.76,7.5 q 0,0.1 0.07,0.18 0.07,0.07 0.18,0.07 0.1,0 0.18,-0.07 Q 6.26,7.61 6.26,7.5 6.26,7.19 6.48,6.97 6.7,6.75 7,6.75 7.1,6.75 7.18,6.68 7.25,6.61 7.25,6.5 Z M 9,7.5 Q 9,8.32 8.42,8.92 7.84,9.5 7.01,9.5 6.19,9.5 5.6,8.92 5,8.340093 5,7.5 5,6.67 5.58,6.09 6.17,5.5 6.99,5.5 q 0.83,0 1.41,0.5867347 0.59,0.59 0.59,1.41 z M 1,12 H 13 V 11 H 1 Z M 10,7.5 Q 10,6.25 9.12,5.38 8.24,4.5 7,4.5 5.75,4.5 4.88,5.38 4,6.26 4,7.5 4,8.75 4.88,9.62 5.76,10.5 7,10.5 8.25,10.5 9.12,9.63 10,8.76 10,7.51 Z m -8,-5 h 3 v -1 H 2 Z M 1,4 H 13 V 3.06 2 H 6.54 L 6,3 H 1 Z M 14,2 v 10 q 0,0.41 -0.3,0.7 Q 13.4,13 13,13 H 1 Q 0.59,13 0.3,12.7 0,12.41 0,12 V 2 Q 0,1.59 0.3,1.3 0.58,1 1,1 H 13 Q 13.41,1 13.7,1.3 14,1.6 14,2 Z" />
 
 </svg> - Это SVG</p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку иконка сделана 14 на 14px а мне нужно 16px, я увеличиваю SVG и тут получается размытая лажа. (Естественно, 14px выглядят одинаково хорошо, но в этом и дело, получается, я не могу масштабировать SVG!) Никто не говорит, что SVG это плохо, SVG - это картинка и ведет себя так, как вела бы себя картинка.

А шрифт на мелких размерах, сохраняет читаемость благодаря [хинтингу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

В SVG теряются детали, смазываются края, в общем, выглядит коряво. Конечно, всегда есть возможность сделать "Pixel-perfect" SVG (располагать вектор ровно по пикселям), чтобы картинка была четкой на нужном размере. Но тогда куда денется хваленая гибкость вектора? Что если потребуется немного увеличить иконку? А что если дизайнер нарисует вам кривой вектор?

Выходит SVG - это хорошее решение только для программиста. Для программиста, которому плевать как выглядит конечный продукт. С другой стороны, если вы будете делать идеальные "Pixel-perfect" иконки и не будете изменять их размер, SVG не будет хуже (но практика показывает обратное)

И, кстати, SVG [еще и медленнее отрисовывается](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2015/05/icons-font-inline-svg-or-background-svgs.html#svg-perf-test-results).

Comment: У вас SVG не качественный. И по-этому отображается плохо, я это и без увеличения вижу.

Comment: @Yuri а вы еще и текст сообщения не дочитываете. Ну да ладно, сделал специально для вас _качественный SVG_

Comment: @Yuri и кстати, шрифту быть _качественным_ не обязательно

Comment: Ну начнём с того, что иконку шрифтом сделать сложнее, чем в SVG. Ну да ладно, там уже у кого как

Comment: @Yuri если в нашей стране все так и будут начинать с того, как что-то сделать проще в производстве, а не качественнее, то так будет продолжаться: ужасные автомобили, разваливающиеся дороги, уродливые здания. Есть хоть одна причина для конечного пользователя использовать SVG?